# facebook option list selectedIndex not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbml

Hy I have t his script:

```
<script> 
function get(obj) {
    return document.getElementById(obj);
}

function getCrer(sel) {
  var value =  get(sel).options[get(sel).selectedIndex].value;  
  get('cbt').value=value;
}
</script>

<select id="combo1" onchange="getCrer(this)">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value=0>Text1</option>
<option value=5>Text2</option>
<option value=9>Text3</option>
</select>
<input name="cbt" type="text" id="cbt"/>
```

I like to work in facebook so when I select from the list the calue shoul go to the input text cbt...but not working in fb. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your onchange event fires, it's passing in the Select *Object* to getCrer, not the Object's ID, so your get method will return null. Try this instead:

```
function getCrer(sel) {
  var value =  sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;  
  get('cbt').value=value;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm...tried it locally, and it worked. Originally, when I tried your code, I would get back an error saying get(sel) is null. Once I made the modification above, the text box would get populated with the value. Are you sure you got rid of both get(sel) references? (There's one right before the .selectedIndex, too)

Comment: SORRY YOU CAN NOT TRY FACEBOOK LOCALLY:) ..IF YOU KNOW A METHOD PLEASE TELL MEE..DOD YOU TRY IT ON FACEBOOK?

Comment: You're right, I wasn't testing it locally on Facebook. It wasn't working as-is straight in a local HTML file. The fix I suggested was for the code you showed in general, not Facebook-specific. Since it didn't work locally, I was approaching it as a general code bug. Once you can get it working locally, then you can blame Facebook for your issue -- not until then. Also, did you mean to yell at me, or was your cap locks button down on accident?

Comment: No worries. Any progress? Another thing I was thinking, is that you might change the name of the get function. That's a pretty common name and it might be bumping into another function that Facebook has defined.